# How to send some data of one template to another template Meteor

Tags: node.js, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

**I want to share some data from template to another template using Meteor.** I have a template i.e allInventory.html on which i am showing some data in table form i added three links there that is. one for view , edit and delete what i want iam getting all the data from backend into one of helper i.e productDetails and i bind an event with view button that will take the data of current user clicked on which product so i have successfully getting the data at my allinventory template but there is another template i.e productDetails on which i want to render or show that data. But stuck with that i have data on allInventory click event but not know how do ishare the same with productDetails template.

Here is my allInventory.js

```
 Template.allInventory.rendered = function() {
Template.allInventory.events({
      "click .btn":function (e){
       data  = $(e.target).attr('data');
    Router.go('productDetail', {data: $(e.target).attr('data')}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});
    console.log("button clicked.."+data);
    console.log(data);

  }
})
```

ProductDetails.js

```
Template.productDetail.rendered = function () {
Template.productDetail.helpers({

 productDetails: function() {  
      return data;
}
    });
```

allInvenrtory.html

```
<button type="button" data ="{{productInfo}}" class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i>View</button>
```

I just simply want to share allInventory template data with productsDetails template.

Any help would be appriciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend avoiding Session for this purpose, since it is a global object, but more importantly, because there are better ways to do it.

You can pass data from the parent templates to the child template using helpers: https://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html#passing-template-content

You can pass data from the child to the parent templates using callbacks https://guide.meteor.com/blaze.html#pass-callbacks

I'd structure this app to have a container (page) template, which will have all the subscriptions and render one of your templates based on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Session variable if you want to share data between templates.

You can follow this guide:

http://meteortips.com/first-meteor-tutorial/sessions/

Answer (score 0):

I would put both template in a third, parent template.

```
 ParentTemplate
  -SharedInfo
  -KidTemplate1
  -KidTemplate2
```

Then having this third template hold the information you want to share across templates.

For that you can use a [ReactiveVar](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/reactive-dict-reactive-vars-and-session-variables/), ensuring that change by template1 code on the parent template is visible in template2 as well.

To access the parent template for the kids, you can do something along those lines :

```
Blaze.TemplateInstance.prototype.parentTemplate = function (levels) {
var view = Blaze.currentView;
if (typeof levels === "undefined") {
    levels = 1;
}
while (view) {
    if (view.name.substring(0, 9) === "Template." && !(levels--)) {
        return view.templateInstance();
    }
    view = view.parentView;
}
};
```